# Refresh BackboneJS on with same URL hash?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, page-refresh

My current backbone application has a url:

```
localhost/#users
```

Is there a way to access `localhost/#users` while at the URL `localhost/#users` so it refreshes the page?

Currently, when I am at `localhost/#users` and I try

`window.location.hash = #users` or `myBackboneRouter.navigate("users")`

it does not trigger a page refresh.

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page that the user is already on?

Comment: I have some ajax bindings that I want to run again on the same page.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by "ajax bindings", but can you just make a function to call them again, then call that function instead of routing?  Seems rather heavy handed to re-render the entire page to refresh some smaller part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `myBackboneRouter.navigate("users", {trigger: true})` will do what you want.

Comment: I tried this but it still won't trigger it :(

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, I see `if (this.fragment == frag) return;` in the navigate function, so I guess that's just short-circuiting the process before trigger would force it to call the route. If you just want it to run the code that runs when you land on that route, just manually call the function that the router routes that hash to. For example, if your router has `routes: {'users': 'users'}` then you can just call `myBackboneRouter.users();` you don't have to call navigate.

Comment: I upvoted the answer but heavi5ide's comment was the real solution for me.

Comment: In backbone 1.0, it reads `this.fragment === frag`.  It's possible to cast the frag passed in a unique String object and force this comparison to be false.

Answer (score 35):

To refresh same page in backbone, you have to use

```
Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
```

Comment: on which part in need to put this code..??

Comment: Thumbs up on this one! It soft-reloads without a full page reload, unlike `window.location.reload()`.

Answer (score 2):

I use these three line of codes to reload my backbone page:

```
router.navigate(Backbone.history.fragment, true);
Backbone.history.loadUrl( Backbone.history.fragment );
router.refresh(true);
```

OR Simply

```
Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
```

Comment: Where would I need to put this in my router? In ever route/when the route is instantiated/somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't you use

```
window.location.reload();
```

Either that or recall your view render() function..

Comment: The problem with window.location.reload() is that it reloads the entire page. This is undesirable if you want your Backbone router to control what is re-rendered without having to reload the entire page.